# How to find out a TCP server's status from the client side (In a redundant server case)?

Tags: c++, c, sockets, networking, tcp

I have a situation here. I have a redundant TCP server setup which takes an input and then throws lots of packets forever. While reading them, I am also trying to keep up with the server's state from TCP client by doing a **send** on the socket. 
   But my servers are redundant sharing a Virtual IP. So if server1 goes down, server2 starts up and uses the same VIP (At all point of time VIP is up and running). So my **send** technique is able to find out this situation.
   My server2 waits for the client's input, but since **send** is not doing the job I expect it to do, I am not able to send the input again.

```
  int status = ::send ( m_sock, s.c_str(), s.size(), MSG_NOSIGNAL );
  if ( status == -1 )
    {
      return false;
    }
  else
    {
      return true;
    }
```

Can someone help how I can figure out this kind of failover?

Comment: What are you asking ? Does your failover already work  and want to find out when a server dies ? Are you asking how to setup such a scenario ?

Comment: Failover works just fine at the server side. But my client gets lost in the process because after the failover the server expects the clients input. My client cannot send the input unless it can understand that failover happened.This is were I am stuck.

Comment: Please explain how the failover works.

Comment: It's a active-standby cluster where all the status is replicated on the standby in realtime. And VIP is my access to the active node (and TCP server). When the active node goes down, VIP will simply be hosted on the other node(and TCP server here becomes active). Edit: So, if my client can somehow find out that the node hosting the VIP is the other one, rest of the things will fall in place!

Comment: So why are you trying to detect "the connection moved to another server" if it's all transparent to you ?

Comment: That's because, after the failover is done, the new server (Though it has every other state) is not actually serving my client. It simply waits for new clients :(

Comment: What do you mean it's not serving you ? If you send it a request, does it treat it as part of the connection ? Does it answer it ? If not, the `send` should fail with `EPIPE`.

Comment: It is not serving me means, the new server won't send any packets. It will wait for new clients ONLY. But from my client pov, it's still on the socket, so it doesn't attempt to resend the connection! And strangely, send doesn't give me a -1...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, piecing things together, I am starting to get a picture here.

- The OP is using **some kind** of failover in which the remote server doesn't actually keep track of the state

The reason you're not getting EPIPE from the send is that things happen this way:

- You `send` data. `send` unblocks and segments start travelling
- The remote server receives data. "Who *is* this guy ? RST!"
- You get the RST but `send` has already returned. The connection is torn but there is no way to inform you of it (it doesn't have any out-of-band mechanism)
- Do **another `send`**

In conclusion, if you want to test if a connection is still alive:

- `send` data
- Wait a bit (RTT and such)
- `send` **again**

If you don't get `EPIPE` after the second `send`, the connection is still up. Another scheme:

- `send` data that should be interpreted as "*Say something* if you're alive!"
- Wait a bit
- If after the timeout you haven't received confirmation, the connection is dead

Comment: It's not that simple. You will get the RST showing up in your program eventually but there is no guarantee it will be on the second send.

Comment: @EJP The RST wil tear the connection so the second RST will fail with -1.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help! I finally figured out that there is a keep alive message sent by the server which I could use to serve my purpose.

Comment: @cnicutar This is just nonsense. What 2nd RST? There is no 2nd RST, because the connection will have been aborted by the first one, so there won't be a 2nd send() that would provoke a 2nd RST. send() will react to the *first* RST after it has arrived. The question is when will the *first* and *only* RST arrive.

Comment: @EJP I mistyped; I meant "the second send" :-)

Comment: @EJP I'll probably get your answer 23 hours later :-))

Comment: @cnicutar You'll get my answer when I post it, which depends on factors you can't control ... I have trouble controlling them myself ;-)

Comment: @cnicutar waiting for what? You made a 'typo' and you corrected it. What are you waiting *for?*

Comment: @EJP Just measuring RTT (kidding)

Answer (score 0):

A TCP session cannot be failed over from one server to another simply by the second server taking over the first's IP address - the TCP session state information must also be replicated from the primary server to the secondary, which requires special software.

Comment: Do you know of such software ? It should be pretty hard to serialize the socket, inpcb, tcpcb and move it to another machine :-?

Comment: @cincutar: Nope, I have only heard of its existence.  The *really* tricky part is synchronising the application layer...

Answer (score 0):

Eventually the send to the server that has taken over must fail because that server won't know about the connection from the client IP:port, so it will issue an RST, which comes back as send() returning -1 and errno = ECONNRESET. This almost certainly won't happen on the first send after the failover because of asynchronicity and buffering.